# Recode 1 raster conditionally, based on many others

Tags: raster, r

the basic premise is that I have 1 chief raster with values 55 to 75 and 6 rasters (A to F) which have all sorts of values between 1 and 15.

If the chief raster has values (e.g.) 50 to 55, those values are replaced by values from raster A in the correct and corresponding position. If the chief raster has values 56 to 58 those values are replaced by values from raster B in the correct position, etc etc.

I've gone down the path of creating a matrix for every raster then creating an index for every value range in the chief raster then subsetting 6 times.

```
ext <- extent(0,10,0,10)

t1 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10,ext)
t1[] <- sample(seq(from = 55, to = 75, by = 1), size = 100, replace = TRUE) 

r1 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10,ext)
r1[] <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 3, by = 1), size = 100, replace = TRUE)
m1 <- as.matrix(r1)
r2 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10,ext)
r2[] <- sample(seq(from = 5, to = 6, by = 1), size = 100, replace = TRUE)
m2 <- as.matrix(r2)
r3 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10,ext)
r3[] <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 6, by = 1), size = 100, replace = TRUE)
m3 <- as.matrix(r3)
r4 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10,ext)
r4[] <- sample(seq(from = 12, to = 15, by = 1), size = 100, replace = TRUE)
m4 <- as.matrix(r4)
r5 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10,ext)
r5[] <- sample(seq(from = 8, to = 11, by = 1), size = 100, replace = TRUE)
m5 <- as.matrix(r5)
r6 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10,ext)
r6[] <- sample(seq(from = 2, to = 14, by = 1), size = 100, replace = TRUE)
m6 <- as.matrix(r6)

m <- as.matrix(t1)

idx1 <- m >=55 & m <=59
idx2 <- m >=60 & m <=62
idx3 <- m >=63 & m <=66
idx4 <- m >=67 & m <=70
idx5 <- m >=71 & m <=74
idx6 <- m ==75

m[idx1] <- m1[idx1]
m[idx2] <- m2[idx2]
m[idx3] <- m3[idx3]
m[idx4] <- m4[idx4]
m[idx5] <- m5[idx5]
m[idx6] <- m6[idx6]

t1[] <- m
```

Is there anything more elegant and quicker?

Comment: Just make a stack or brick of your rasters, write a function using "ifelse" to define your conditions and then pass it to the raster "overlay" function.

Comment: the rasters are a bit large for that i think, multi-billion cells. Though i suppose i could try it.

Comment: Besides efficiency, the point is that large rasters are held "out of memory" and you can define an output raster, on disk, that would also not be read into memory. You solution is forcing the rasters into memory.